# Replacing a VBO in an existing VAO

Tags: performance, opengl, vbo, opengl-3

I have a VAO with VBOs for various vertex attributes: vertex positions, vertex normals, and the element array VBO (all STATIC_DRAW), such that rendering an instance simply requires:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, <count>, <type>, 0);
```

However, I want to draw multiple instances of an object (I'm restricted to the OS X GL 3.2 core profile BTW) with different vertex texture (s,t) coordinates for each instance. The texcoord VBOs use the STREAM_DRAW hint (although I might get away with DYNAMIC_DRAW).

Is it more efficient to bind the VAO, bind the current texcoord VBO, and set the attribute pointer via `glVertexAttribPointer`, finalize the VAO with `glBindVertexArray(0)` and draw the  new instance with different texture coordinates? Or does the cost of updating a VAO make this a poor approach? What about updating the texcoord VBO with `glBufferSubData` in a bound VAO?

I'd really appreciate some feedback before benchmarking separate approaches, since the *wrong* choice will result in significant refactoring.

Comment: Been looking for more information about this. I'm in the process of upgrading my engine to GL3.2 myself, so will try to post about my findings.

Comment: @Grimmy - did you find anything interesting?

Comment: I've ended up with the "create lots of VAOs"-approach. I do still have the ability to mess with VAO bindings if needed, but haven't had any performance issues with it yet. To be fair, I only have a handful of instances were the same mesh uses different data for a specific attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create multiple VAO. vertex array objects are lightweight, and they are used to setup vertex arrays all at once...

A VBO can be bound to multiple VAO, making your life easier and faster.

If you want, at some point, another attribute configuration, throw away the old VAO and create a new one.

Comment: This is something I considered: VAO setup is not time-critical - it's setup code, but if the texcoords change, a VAO must be created or updated during the rendering loop. My understanding is that VAO setup does a lot of work to validate the buffers, bounds, and internal consistency, so that it can be used efficiently at the expense of initialization costs.

Comment: If you can't  create all needed VAO at setup time, your only option is to profile the VAO create/update solutions and VBO update solution. I've never noticed latencies cause by VAO initialization at loop time, but this is very application specific.

Comment: Luca, thanks for your own observations. VAOs are certainly lightweight, there's a good pseudo-code example [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Array_Object#VAO_State), and the same amount of (shared) VBO data will exist in my code anyway. Have you found switching between multiple VAOs to result in significant latency? Or am I contradicting myself in that VAO bindings should be efficient after the expense of the setup.